# Auto Update Django Model based on other model fields

Tags: python, django

What is the best method for updating a model field based on the results of another model.

i.e I have the following,

```
from django.db import models

class ValidateResult(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class TotalResult(models.Model):
    total = models.IntegerField()
```

What I require is `TotalResults.total` to be a total count of all fields within `ValidateResult.number`. I want to write this into the model so each time I update the `ValidateResults` model is auto updates the totals in the `TotalResult` model.

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any relation between your models ??? If not I just don't see the point of the `TotalResult` model. And even if yes, I still don't see the point FWIW - SQL databases have aggregation functions like "SUM"...

Comment: Nope. But I just want to look at one table to see the results.

Comment: So you think having a table with a single field and a single record for some information you can get from a dead simple (and fast) computation  is a sane relational database design ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/) feature:

> Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps allow decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework. In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a set of receivers that some action has taken place. They’re especially useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.

The `django.db.models.signals` module predefines a set of signals sent by the model system. You could use the [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save) signal which is triggered at the end of a model's `save()` method.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel


@receiver(post_save, sender=ValidateResult)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    ...
```